# results not displayed after running sql query in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Created table and loaded data from `txt file` to this table. `select * from tablename` displays all record however when i run select statement with condition, query runs successfully (no error prompts by hive) however no results are displayed. Table exists in the folder.

I ran the below two queries-

```
select * from plan1 where contid = "%H0001%";
select * from plan1 where contid = "H0001";
```

any thoughts? TIA

Comment: have you tried using like ??
e.g `select * from plan1 where contid like "%H0001%";`

Comment: can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Are you sure the columns were correctly named?

Comment: @Debjit - that worked..duh to me..that option didn't cross my mind..thanks!

Comment: thx madhu and Charlie.